# Evaluate $\frac{4}{\sin^2 20^\circ} - \frac{4}{\sin^2 40^\circ} + 64\sin^2 20^\circ$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Evaluate the following expression:$$\frac{4}{\sin^2 20^\circ} - \frac{4}{\sin^2 40^\circ} + 64\sin^2 20^\circ$$
I tried combining the whole into a single fraction and using double-angle identity, product/sum to sum/product, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is your question?  Also when you write $\sin 20^2$ do you mean $\left(\sin20^\circ\right)^2$?  This is usually written $\sin^220^\circ$.

Comment: This is actually quite an interesting question (I think you mean : find the value of (mathematical expression)). If you make the requested edits, and add maybe one or two steps of what simplification you attempted, your question can get more attention.

Comment: @saulspatz yes.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2Fsin%5E2%2820%29-4%2Fsin%5E2%2840%29%2B64sin%5E2%2820%29) says $32$

Answer (score 4):

Per the identity
$\sin3t =3\sin t -4\sin^3t$,
it is straightforward to verify that $\sin20$, $\sin40$, $-\sin80$ are the roots of
$4x^3-3x+\frac{\sqrt3}2=0$, which leads to

$$\sin20\sin40\sin80=\frac{\sqrt3}8$$
Then

\begin{align}
& \frac{4}{\sin^2 20^\circ} - \frac{4}{\sin^2 40^\circ} + 64\sin^2 20^\circ\\
=& \frac{64}3\left(4\sin^240\sin^280 -4\sin^220\sin^280+3\sin^220 \right)\\
 =& \frac{64}3\left((1-\cos80)(1+\cos20)-(1-\cos40)(1+\cos20) + \frac32(1-\cos40)\right)\\
 =& \frac{64}3\left(\frac32 - \cos80 -\frac12\cos40 
-\cos20\cos80 +\cos20\cos40\right)\\
 =& 32 + \frac{64}3\left(- \cos80 -\frac12\cos40 
-\frac12(\cos60-\cos80) +\frac12(\cos20+\cos60)\right)\\
 =& 32 + \frac{32}3\left(\cos 20- \cos40 -\cos80
\right) \\
= &32 + \frac{32}3\left(\cos 20- 2\cos60\cos20
\right)\\
=& 32
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proof at the top for the value of $\sin20\sin40\sin80$, very nice, I hadn't seen that particular one before.

Answer (score 0):

Formulae for $\sin4x,\,\sin5x$ provide another solution. Let $S:=\sin^220^\circ\ne\sin^260^\circ=\tfrac34$ so$$\begin{align}0&=\frac{\sin^2100^\circ-\sin^280^\circ}{S}\\&=(5-20S+16S^2)^2-16(1-S)(1-2S)^2\\&=256S^4-576S^3+432S^2-120S+9\\&=(4S-3)(64S^3-96S^2+36S-3)\\\implies64S^3-96S^2+36S-3&=0\\\implies\frac{4}{S}-\frac{1}{S(1-S)}+64S&=\frac{3-4S+64S^2-64S^3}{S(1-S)}\\&=32.\end{align}$$